# Python range - No iteration when start == end?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title says.

Tested using:

```
for x in range (0,0):
        print(str(x))
```

I am expecting to see "0", but nothing prints.

I'm using Python 3 and was hoping:

```
 for x in range(x,y)
```

Would at least get me one iteration when x == y, but it seems that isn't the case... is there a better way I could be doing this rather than manually handling the x == y scenario?

Comment: `for x in range (0,1)` is basically `for x=0; x<1; x++`

Comment: The number of iterations you get is always `y - x`, so 0 in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `range` is half-inclusive

`range(x, y)` includes `x` and excludes `y`. Use `range(x, y + 1)` instead, so for your example you'd like to use `range(0, 1)` in your first codeblock.

Comment: I see now, I misunderstood the documentation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As by the [documentation of range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), range will return the largest `start + i * step` less than stop. As 0 + step can never be less than 0, it will return an empty list. In your case you would want to use `range(x, y + 1)`.